# PHP Form multiple values

Tags: php

I have a form when you can select multiple values for an element but when i run send the form data i get this error:

```
ContextErrorException
Notice: Undefined index: optiuni
```

This is the code in question.
Form:

```
                          <select multiple name="optiuni[]" style="width:300px;" class="form-control">
                            <option value="A">Deschidere la livrare</option>
                            <option value="S">Livrare sambata</option>
                            <option value="D">Livrare din sediul FAN Courier</option>
                          </select>
```

Foreach function parsing the selection options

```
foreach ($_POST['optiuni'] as $selected_option) {
    $optiuni .= $selected_option;
}
echo $optiuni;
```

Comment: What ís present in the $_POST variable?

Comment: Do you send a POST form?

Comment: @brombeer, yes this is the form <form action="generare_awb_test.php" method="post"> that has the select multiple name

Comment: And if you dump the $_POST var, what's it value?

Comment: @Robinvb in var_dump it appears as optiuni https://pastebin.com/i9zDSedH

Comment: IS this error happens after submitting the form?

One possibility is, this could happen before you submitting the form (and no $_POST['optiuni'] is there until you submit the form). In that case you need to check if the $_POST is defined and then only run the for loop.

Comment: @Chandana The error happens after submitting the form. The form is in one php file and the errors appears in the php file that uses the data submitted by the form.

Comment: Could you share more code? Are you maybe redirecting after the post request? I'd debug it step by step. optiuni is present in the post where you dumped it, so keep dumping it on places further in the application untill it's empty. Then see what's causing that! Because, based on your dump, it is present in the request :)

Comment: `ContextErrorException` .. are you using any framework? Symfony?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the error was because of Debug mode being activated in prestashop. Everything works fine after deactivating it.